# Count number of times a method is called?

Tags: java

i'm trying to count the number of times a method is called. I have 3 classes at the moment, Circle.java, Picture.java and PictureTest.java

In the circle.java there is;

```
public class Circle
{
    private int diameter;
    private int xPosition;
    private int yPosition;
    private String color;
    private boolean isVisible;
    private int instances;

    /**
     * Create a new circle at default position with default color.
     */
    public Circle()
    {
        diameter = 30;
        xPosition = 20;
        yPosition = 60;
        color = "blue";
        isVisible = false;
        instances = 0;
        instances++;
        System.out.println(instances);
    }
```

In the Picture.java:

```
public class Picture
{
    private Circle sun;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Picture
     */
    public Picture()
    {
        // nothing to do... instance variables are automatically set to null
    }

    /**
     * Draw this picture.
     */
    public void draw()
    {    
        sun = new Circle();
        sun.changeColor("yellow");
        sun.moveHorizontal(180);
        sun.moveVertical(-10);
        sun.changeSize(60);
        sun.makeVisible();

        sun = new Circle();
        sun.changeColor("yellow");
        sun.moveHorizontal(180);
        sun.moveVertical(-10);
        sun.changeSize(60);
        sun.makeVisible();

        sun = new Circle();
        sun.changeColor("yellow");
        sun.moveHorizontal(180);
        sun.moveVertical(-10);
        sun.changeSize(60);
        sun.makeVisible();
    }
```

And the PictureTest.java is where the main is:

```
public class PictureTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Picture p = new Picture();
        p.draw();

   }
}
```

When I run it, instead of it printing 3 because there are three suns, it prints:

```
1
1
1
```

I'm not completely sure why this is, but I think it might have something to do with the fact that I'm printing from the Circle class so every time a circle is created it prints the 1. I've tried to change it so it prints the instances from the main in PictureTest but I can't get it working.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `instances = 0;` does? And think of `static` members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
instances = 0;
instances++;
```

`instances` will always equal `1`.

What you need to do is make `instances` a `static` variable.

```
public class Circle
{
    public static int instances = 0;
}
```

then inside your constructor class

```
instances ++;
```

Comment: Thanks! Not a massive issue, but it now prints "1, 2, 3" instead of just the "3". I'm aware this is because it prints every time the Circle class is called so where do I need to put the print to fix this?

Comment: Wherever you want to see it.. I mean, I'd take the `System.out.println()` statement of the constructor and put it at the end of the `draw` method.

Comment: Problem is that the draw method is in a different file and I can't work out how to make that work. If I just put the print in the draw then I get the error that it can't find the symbol.

Comment: You refer to it as `Cirlce.instance`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your  `private int instances;` variable to static

Answer (score 2):

You have a different instance of `instances` for each instance of a `Circle`

If you don't want that to be the case, than make `instances` static

```
private static int instances;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make static variable for example `static int counter = 0;`  and increment its value in each method :

```
 void veryImportantMethod(){
 //great code goes here
 counter ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `instances` is a member variable, meaning it is within the membership of the `Object` (in this case the `Circle` object).  As you create new `Object`s, you will create new instances of the `instance` variable.

To alleviate this, you need to make the variable `static`, which means that it will be shared across all `Object`s of the class.

Other alternatives exist too.  For example, you could make it live outside of the `Circle` class, and update it in coordination of creating additional `Circle` objects.  How you would go about this would depend heavily on the exact problems you are trying to solve, but it could be as easy as

```
 Circle one = new Circle(...);
 circleCount++;
 Circle two = new Circle(...);
 circleCount++;
```

Or, if you prefer a `Factory` pattern

```
 Circle circle = CircleFactory.newCircle(...);
 Circle circle = CircleFactory.newCircle(...);
 int count = CircleFactory.getCreatedCircleCount();
```

where CircleFactory has a method like

```
 private static int circleCount;

 public static Circle newCircle(...) {
   circleCount++;
   return new Circle(...);
 }

 public int getCreatedCircleCount() {
   return circleCount;
 }
```

In short, there are many ways to do this, but in time you will find how to select the best method considering the problem you are solving, the maintenance needs, and the ability to make your code more readable after you haven't been working with it for the last few weeks (or years).

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer : "every time a circle is created it prints the 1". To avoid this, you have to declare the field `instances` as `static`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
private static int fooCounter = 0;
private static int barCounter = 0;
private static int objectInstance = 0;

public MySuperTrackedObject(){
    objectInstance++;
    ...
}

public MySuperTrackedObject(String aGoodName){
    objectInstance++;
    ...
}

public void foo(){
    fooCounter ++;
    ...
}
public void bar(){
    barCounter ++;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`instances` has to be `static` in order to have a single value for the entire class, not one per instance. Also note that the following code in the constructor won't work like you want it to even after making it static:

```
instances = 0; //this line here will cause your instances to revert to zero
instances++;   //and then, to one, no matter how many you're supposed to have
```